# FileNotFoundException in Android with HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, http, junit

I'm getting the following error whenever I try an run unit tests in Android - tests that pass when run outside of Android:

```
07-18 15:43:44.816: W/System.err(545): uk.co.redfruit.libraries.srpDB.exceptions.SRBClientException: java.io.FileNotFoundExce$
07-18 15:43:44.816: W/System.err(545):  at uk.co.redfruit.libraries.srpDB.SRPDBClient.getContent(SRPDBClient.java:116)
07-18 15:43:44.816: W/System.err(545):  at uk.co.monkeypower.android.straightrazordatabase.test.SRPDBClientTest.testGetConten$
07-18 15:43:44.826: W/System.err(545):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 15:43:44.826: W/System.err(545):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-18 15:43:44.826: W/System.err(545):  at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
07-18 15:43:44.826: W/System.err(545):  at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
07-18 15:43:44.826: W/System.err(545):  at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
07-18 15:43:44.826: W/System.err(545):  at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
07-18 15:43:44.826: W/System.err(545):  at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
07-18 15:43:44.826: W/System.err(545):  at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
07-18 15:43:44.826: W/System.err(545):  at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
07-18 15:43:44.826: W/System.err(545):  at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
07-18 15:43:44.826: W/System.err(545):  at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:529)
07-18 15:43:44.836: W/System.err(545):  at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1448)
07-18 15:43:44.836: W/System.err(545): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://straightrazorplace.com/srpwiki/index.$
07-18 15:43:44.836: W/System.err(545):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getIn$
07-18 15:43:44.836: W/System.err(545):  at uk.co.redfruit.libraries.srpDB.SRPDBClient.getContent(SRPDBClient.java:106)
07-18 15:43:44.836: W/System.err(545):  ... 13 more
```

I'm aware of a bug that appears to make this happen in Android 4.x+, but I get exactly the same error when running in Gingerbread.

The code that causes the error is as follows:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(targetURL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    connection.getInputStream()));
            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String content = null;
            while ((content = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(content + "\n");
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new SRBClientException(e);
        }
```

I have the INTERNET permission in my manifest and the url does exist - I can access it in a browser.  Can anyone see where I'm going wrong or what I'm missing?

**Update:** I tried using  [basic http client](https://code.google.com/p/basic-http-client/) as an attempted workaround.  It didn't work, but it provided a completely different error.  It showed that I was getting a 403, which, in the previous attempt, simply resulted in FileNotFound, but this time also caused a JSON exception as the html error message that was returned couldn't (obviously) be parsed as JSON.

I'm guessing then that this is a server side issue, although I'm baffled as to why I get a 403 in Android, but in no other context...

Comment: can you reach targetURL with your browser?

Comment: yes, I can.  Also, the tests all pass when run in junit outside of Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the server was blocking whatever the default user agent is (nothing perhaps?) and was returning 403.

By setting it to a standard browser user agent (in this case I used Chrome) it worked.

Answer (score 0):

FileNotFoundException is thrown when the server returns a 404 (and other codes).  I'm guessing your test is trying to reach `http://straightrazorplace.com/srpwiki/index.html`, which gives me a 404 in Chrome.

Comment: fair guess, although it's actually aiming for http://straightrazorplace.com/srpwiki/index.php?curid=3381&action=render which doesn't return 404. Also, as I said, these tests pass in a non Android context - i.e. straight junit.

Comment: Is your server receiving the request (check logs)? If so, is it serving a non-400 response? Perhaps the URL is being mangled.

Comment: Don't have access to the server logs. Is ther eany other way I could check.  Using debugging, the URL looks fine just before a connection is attempted.  Obviously, though, there might be plenty of opportunity in the connection process to break the URL.